# Running out of memory for a Fully Connected Layer for a 3D Tensor (PyTorch)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to Pytorch and am trying to implement a 3D neural network.

I have a Pytorch tensor of size 112 (filters) x 20 x 20 x 20. I must pass this through a Fully Connected Layer, consisting of 128 nodes. The output should therefore be a 128 (filters) x 20 x 20 x 20 tensor.

Naively, I would flatten the tensor and pass it through a Pytorch Linear layer. However, Pytorch wants to allocate 3417GB of RAM for this layer, which I (perhaps obviously) do not have.

The minimum working example is shown below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

test = torch.randn(112, 20, 20, 20)
test = test.view(-1, 112*20*20*20)

layer = nn.Linear(112*20*20*20, 128*20*20*20)

out = layer(test)
```

What I would like to do is apply a Fully Connected Layer to each 20x20x20 element. This would then consist of 20x20x20 fully connected layers, applied independently to each element. However, I have no idea how to implement this.

It is very likely I have misunderstood some aspect of this. How is it that I can build this layer?

Comment: If your linear layer should have 128 nodes then it should have 128 outputs, not 128*20*20*20. The way you've defined it the linear layer you created has (112*20*20*20) * (128*20*20*20) = 917 504 000 000 weights (not including bias weights) which is probably why you're running out of memory.

Comment: Note that you can simply use a size-1 convolution for this. I suppose you are using 3D convolution? So you would use a filter size of (1 x 1 x 1) and 128 filters. This is equivalent to applying the same fully-connected network at each position in the 3D grid.